# Inputing using Scanner class

Tags: java

What I understood from my past experiences is  `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()` would keep on searching until the integer or the double is found in the same or the next line it doesn't matter,while to read a string as input through scanner class `next()` considers those strings before space and keeps the cursor in the same line, where as `nextLine()` would consider the leftovers by the `next()` if used before the `nextLine()` in code,could someone help me understand this in more detail,especially about `nextLine()` where it starts and where the cursor ends? Also, please tell me if any mistakes I thought are correct.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first understanding is wrong.

> what i understood from my past experiences is .nextInt() or
>   .nextDouble() would keep on searching until the integer or the double
>   is found in the same or the next line it doesn't matter

`nextInt()` and `nextDouble()` waits for the integer and double respectively. If it gets string instead of it's expectation, it throws `InputMismatchException`.

You can run this code and see for yourself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        s.nextInt();
    }
}
```

According to your quote:

> .nextInt() or .nextDouble() would keep on searching until the integer
>   or the double is found in the same or the next line it doesn't matter

Give input: `Abcdf234gd`. You won't get `234`. You get `InputMismatchException`.

For `.next()` and `.nextLine()`,

`.next()` : Only reads and returns a string till it encounters a space or `EOF`.

`.nextLine()` : Returns string till it encounters `\n` or `\r` or `EOF`. Means, it returns whole line.

---

**Cursor Positions**

**`next()`**:

Consider the string:

```
ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ
```

Initial Position:

```
->ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ
```

When you call `next()`, the cursor moves to:

```
ABC ->DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ
```

and returns `ABC`

---

**`nextLine()`**:

Consider the string:

```
ABC DEF GHI JKL 
MNO PQR STU VWX
YZ
```

Initial Position:

```
->ABC DEF GHI JKL
MNO PQR STU VWX 
YZ
```

When you call `nextLine()`, the cursor moves to next line:

```
ABC DEF GHI JKL
->MNO PQR STU VWX
YZ
```

and returns `ABC DEF GHI JKL`.

I hope it helps.